# Javscript - if else problem (changing style color if a number is negative or positive)

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I created a simple program that contains two buttons "higher" that adds 1 to the number and "lower" that subtracts 1 from the same number. **When the number is negative it must change its color to red and when it is positive it must become green but that doesn't work.**
Here's the javascript

```
        let num = 0;
        function higher() {
            num ++;
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
        }
        function lower() {
            num --;
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
        }

        // (conditionals statements below do not work for an unknown reason)
        if (num < 0) {
            document.getElementById("number").style.color = "red";
        } else if (num > 0) {
            document.getElementById("number").style.color = "green";
        }
```

Here's the Html body

```
<body>
    <div class="counter">
        <div id="number">0</div>
        <button onmousedown="higher()" class="btn_high">Higher</button>
        <button onclick="lower()" class="btn_low">Lower</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's an example of how the program should look
https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Counter-Project/

Comment: The conditionals never get executed after the click. Make another function to do the updates and invoke it from within your higher/lower functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the conditional statement inside a function and then call that function on each button click like this

```
    let num = 0;

    function higher() {
        num ++;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
        colorChange();
    }

    function lower() {
        num --;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
        colorChange();
    }

    function colorChange(){
        if (num < 0) {
            document.getElementById("number").style.color = "red";
        } else if (num > 0) {
            document.getElementById("number").style.color = "green";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is calling the code at the end, so you'll never see those results. Try wrapping your conditional in a function, then calling that function at the end of `higher()` and `lower()`. For example:

```
let num = 0;

function higher() {
    num++;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
    checkNumberAndApplyStyles();
}

function lower() {
    num--;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
    checkNumberAndApplyStyles();
}

function checkNumberAndApplyStyles() {
    if (num < 0) {
        console.log('under')
        document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (num > 0) {
        document.getElementById("number").style.color = "green";
    }
```